# How do I add variable times to Time.now in Rails (eval?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time, eval

Well this seems like it should be a simple thing but I can't seem to find what I need. Currently I have two variables: frequency and period. frequency is set to a number (eg 1) and period is set to "month" or "year". What I want to do is is use these variables to calculate x months from now.

I've seen the 1.month.from_now and 1.year.from_now but what I need is something like:

```
eval("#{frequency}.#{period.downcase}.from_now")
```

but I'm not sure about the use of `eval` as I'm new to Rails/Ruby and in PHP the use of eval usually means you're doing something wrong.

Is `eval` evil in Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eval is pretty slow. You can use [Object#send](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999):

```
irb(main):003:0> frequency = 1
irb(main):004:0> period = "month"
irb(main):005:0> frequency.send(period).from_now
=> Mon, 30 May 2011 16:57:12 UTC +00:00
```

And you can read about the speed [here](http://www.khelll.com/blog/ruby/ruby-dynamic-method-calling/).

Comment: Thanks nash and Thilo, just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your own method and use your variables to calculate your **x month from**
for example:

```
def my_x_month(period,frequency)
  case period
   when "month"
    period.month.from_now
   when "year"
    period.year.from_now
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really just a ruby question, not Rails specific. Use this:

```
frequency.send(period.downcase).from_now
```

that simply invokes a method called "month" of "year" on frequency.